# TCA9555 Analog I/O

Tags: microcontroller, analog, i2c

I understand that the TCA955 is an I/O extender that communicates via a I2C bus. What I can't figure out is whether this chip will take analog inputs as well as digital inputs. I'm trying to add more analog pins to a micro controller, so if this won't work, can you recommend something that will.

Comment: The TCA955 provides **digital** i/o pins, controlled by I2C. For reading analog inputs, you can use an external A-to-D converter (ADC), or if your uC has its own ADC, an *analog multiplexer*.

Answer (score 3):

What @ThePhoton said.

[TCA9555](http://www.ti.com/product/tca9555) is a purely digital I/O expander.

Not having enough analog inputs on a μC is a frequent problem.  Here are some of the solutions:

1. Choose a bigger μC with more A/D channels.
2. External A/D.  There are lots of external A/D with I<sup>2</sup>C interface.  [AD7998](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-to-digital-converters/ad-converters/ad7998/products/product.html), for example.  The choice would depend on the number of channels and resolution bits that you require.  You can get additional benefits from an external A/D, such as: more resolution bits than in the μC's A/D, differential channels.
3. Analog multiplexor (analog mux) in front of a μC channel.  CD4051 is a classic one.  I've had success with [ADG728](http://www.analog.com/en/switchesmultiplexers/analog-switches/adg728/products/product.html), which can be controlled through I<sup>2</sup>C.

1. and 2. tend to be more common than 3.  Usually, if you can add an extra IC for the analog mux, you might as well add an external A/D instead of the mux.